# Failed to generate or install certificate

Tags: django, ssl, aws-lambda, lets-encrypt

I am using  [Zappa](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa) to deploy to my Django code to AWS Lambda. In that process I have to renew my Domain SSL certificate as it has expired. I tried to create new by doing 
So I tried to create a new SSL key by doing

```
 $ openssl genrsa 2048 > account.key;
```

And Added my Domain name and Path to zappa_settings.json file.
I tried to run

```
 $ zappa certify production
```

This is what the Error I am getting

```
 $ zappa certify production
 Calling certify for stage production..
 Are you sure you want to certify? [y/n] y
 Certifying domain xxxx.domain.com ..
 Error registering: 400 {
 "type": "urn:acme:error:malformed",
 "detail": "Provided agreement URL 
 [https://letsencrypt.org/documents/LE-SA-v1.1.1-August-1-2016.pdf] does not match current agreement URL [https://letsencrypt.org/documents/LE-SA-v1.2-November-15-2017.pdf]",
"status": 400
 }
 Failed to generate or install certificate! :(
 ==============
```

I find the link https://letsencrypt.org/documents/LE-SA-v1.2-November-15-2017.pdf has nothing but "404 Not Found" Error. what is the problem ? 
And also do we have to run 
     $ zappa certify everytime we need to
renew the certificate ?

Answer (score 0):

Its a temporary error which is being caused due to some changes on the subscribe agreement. Update zappa again tomorrow and try again.

https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/subscriber-agreement-update-november-15-2017/45607